# Shell loop returns only one file

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have a shell script which looks for files of ceratin format,and takes parts of string and call in a command, in a for loop because I have couple of files which needed to be printed out.
The following are files I need to return into `sub.sh`

```
CAP_1_34.yml
SAP_34_5.yml
CAP_1_34.sh
SAP_34_5.sh
```

The following is the script I used,

```
 for name in `ls -1 *yml| xargs -I% echo % | cut -d'_' -f 1`
        do
        ls -1 *.sh |xargs -I% echo submit ajob -J "${name}" -o "${name}".job sh % >sub.sh
done
```

But the above script is is only returning name of last file in sub.sh
Now the `sub.sh` looks like the following

```
submit ajob -J SAP -o SAP.job sh CAP_1_34.sh
submit ajob -J SAP -o SAP.job sh SAP_34_5.sh
```

Where as what I expecting is,

```
submit ajob -J CAP -o CAP.job sh CAP_1_34.sh
submit ajob -J SAP -o SAP.job sh SAP_34_5.sh
```

Comment: Each loop iteration will overwrite `sub.sh`, so only the last value of `$name` will be observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for f in *.yml; do
   echo "submit ajob -J ${f%%_*} -o ${f%%_*}.job sh ${f%.*}.sh"
done > sub.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Way too complicated and fragile. Use a glob and parameter expansion operators instead.

```
make_job () {
    printf 'submit job -J "%s" -o "%s" sh "%s"\n' "$1" "$1" "$2"
}
for f in *.yml; do
  prefix=${f%%_*}
  for s in "$prefix"_*.sh; do
    make_job "$prefix" "$s"
  done
done > sub.sh
```